# Can't see the list of events/actions during the Ctrl+drag operation in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, swift2, nscontrol

I working with NSxxx kind of controls. It is OS X project.

I expect to see the drop-down control "Event" between the fields "Name" and "Type", with the list of the control library events.

[image]

Why I can not see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most NSControl subclassed objects are simple enough that you just respond to an @IBAction, and that is the "event."  For more complex controls you can create outlets to a delegate and sometimes to a datasource as well (e.g. NSTableView).

Your question indicates you're using an NSSlider, and that is perhaps best dealt with using bindings in Xcode, not IBActions.

Comment: By the way: "How to achieve all the list of actions/events of the control easy and quick?"